# I am using react native, node.js and mysql and I have problem with fetching images to my application

Tags: react-native

I am new in this field and I have a problem with fetching image from database to my application I use blob data type for image to store in my database.

this is my node.js code:

```
app.get('/lawyer',(req,res)=>{
    const sql="SELECT id,profile_img FROM lawyer_page";
    DB.query(sql,(err,dataa)=>{
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        
        return res.send(dataa)
    })
})
```

and this is my react native code:

```
const fetchData = async()=>{
setIsLoading(true)
try{
  const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.7:8085/lawyer')
  const result = await response.json()

  setDbase(result)
} catch(error){
  console.log(error)
}finally{
  setIsLoading(false)
  
}
}

useEffect(()=>{
  fetchData();
},[])

 {
        dbase?.map((item)=>(
          <LawyersCard 
           key={item.id} 
           id={item.id}
           imgUrl={item.profile_img}
           name={item.name}  
           exper={item.experience}
           city={item.city}
           level={item.level}
           degree={item.degree}
           mobile={item.mobile}
          />
        ))
      }
```

and this is how it show up in my browser:

[data from database that selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UKi5.jpg)

I just want to retrieve data image from database to my application using react native node.js and mysql.
thank you to help me to solve my problem and if you have a better way to show image from data base to my application I will be appreciate it.

thank you.

Comment: Your script does what it is supposed todo: returns the image as binary data and that's what you have in react.js. Your question does not tell us what's wrong with this output.

Comment: nothing wrong with the output but how can I deal with the image as binary data how can I make the output that the react native can show the image in the application. @Shadow

Comment: OK, so your question has nothing to do with mysql or node.js, you just want to know how to handle the output in react. Removed irrelevant tags. You should add your clarification to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we store images on server as a file, and store names/paths to those files in the database.
I assume you are really storing image data on database.
In that case you need to make

```js
 
        dbase?.map((item)=>(
          <LawyersCard 
           key={item.id} 
           id={item.id}
           imgUrl={ URL.createObjectURL(item.profile_img)}
           name={item.name}  
           exper={item.experience}
           city={item.city}
           level={item.level}
           degree={item.degree}
           mobile={item.mobile}
          />
        ))
      }
```

URL.createObjectURL creates link to data . so img like elements can access it via src attribute.